# memset showing wrong results

Tags: c, memset

The code is to check the working of memset in C. memset initializes the array correctly for 0 but when I try initialize it with 10 it initializes the array with some very large garbage value .What's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int dp[10008],i;
    memset(dp,10,sizeof(dp));
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    printf("%d\n",dp[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: memset initialises each byte with 10. when you interpret four bytes with 10 in them ( or 8 or whatever ) then you get these values.. you need to loop over the data and set each integer ( not byte ) to 10 if thats what you want

Comment: @amdixon: Yep. Why not write this as an answer?

Comment: While *a* solution to this could be the same in both C and C++, C++ have other alternatives that would be better (IMO). Please pick the language you want the solution in.

Comment: You shouldn't allocate large amounts of data on the stack. That is, unless you are a fan of stack overflow.

Comment: @Lundin - 40 kB isn't a large amount of data.  For example, the default stack size for a thread on 32 bit Linux is 2 MB, and the main thread stack can grow to much larger than that.

Answer (score 12):

**man memset**

> ```
>        void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        The  memset()  function  fills  the  first  n  bytes of the memory area
>        pointed to by s with the constant byte c.
> ```

your code :

```
memset(dp,10,sizeof(dp));
```

then is initialising all bytes in `dp` to 10.

so your array looks like ( bytewise ) :

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 00001010 | 00001010 | 00001010 | 00001010 | ...
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

and if you interpret that as an integer you get ( some large value ).

note above is based on sizeof int as 4 for illustrative purposes only..

To meet your needs of initialising all ints to 10 use :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int dp[10008],i;
    for(i=0;i<10008;i++)
    {
      dp[i] = 10;
    }
    // do other stuff here..
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The memset should be removed entirely from the modified code.

Comment: thanks, too much copy+paste ;)

Comment: In case anybody is tempted to apply premature optimization to your good, clear code: compilers are pretty good at optimizing simple loops and I'd expect that the compiler would convert this loop to a big memset anyway

Comment: @LPs `memset` sets bytes to `value`. Every byte is 8 bits, and 10 is `0x00001010`, so why would it be `0x10101010`?

Comment: @EnzoFerber I misunderstood. I thought was the array representation, not the byte binary representation.

Comment: @EnzoFerber BTW what you wrote is wrong 10 is `0x0000000a` or `0b00001010`

Comment: @LPs Oh yeah. That would be hex, and would be `0x0a` (8 bits) in hex. I wanted to do the binary thing with the `b`.

Answer (score -1):

**memset** sets bytes and works for characters because they are single bytes, but integers are not.